# How to put data-clearing with image_tag and link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

How to put data-clearing with image_tag and link_to ?
I tried this but its not working

```
<ul class="clearing-thumbs small-block-grid-4" data-clearing>
          <% @galleries.each do |f| %>


            <!-- <a href= f.image.url class="gal"> -->

              <%= link_to link_to f.image.url , image_tag(f.image.url(:medium)) %></li>


            <div class="box_bot">
                <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>  
                  <%= link_to "Delete", f,class: "btn", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this?" } %>
                <% end %>
                  <!-- <a href="#" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></a> --> 

      </div>

      <% end %> </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
          <% @galleries.each do |f| %>


       <li>     <%= image_tag (f.image.url)%>
 <% image_tag (f.image.url(:medium)) %></li>
```

Thanks I fix it

Answer (score 0):

There is a duplicate `link_to link_to`. You probably need only one.

Beside that I suggest to use parenthesise and fix the indentation for readability:

```
<ul class="clearing-thumbs small-block-grid-4" data-clearing>
  <% @galleries.each do |f| %>

    <%= link_to(f.image.url, class: 'gal') do %>    
      <%= image_tag(f.image.url(:medium)) %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="box_bot">
      <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>  
        <%= link_to('Delete', f,
                    class: 'btn', 
                    method: :delete, 
                    data: { 
                      confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?'
                    }) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Furthermore your example includes a closing `</li>`, but there is no opening `<li>`. I remove the closing `</li>`, because just a closing tag is invalid HTML. You will have to add both (opening and closing tag) to the above code at appropriate places.